# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for not working with has_many relationship and cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, accepts-nested-attributes

I'm using the [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem to build a form that creates a Tournament. A Tournament `has_many` Games. Cocoon lets me dynamically add more games to the form.

When I call `@tournament.save`, it generates the following errors:

```
Games team one must exist
Games team two must exist
```

**tournament.rb**

```
class Tournament < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :games, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**game.rb**

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tournament, optional: false
  belongs_to :team_one, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :team_two, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :field, optional: true
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_12_24_011346) do
  ...
  create_table "club_teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "fields", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "tournament_id", null: false
    t.string "team_one_type", null: false
    t.bigint "team_one_id", null: false
    t.string "team_two_type", null: false
    t.bigint "team_two_id", null: false
    t.bigint "field_id", null: false
    t.date "date"
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["field_id"], name: "index_games_on_field_id"
    t.index ["team_one_type", "team_one_id"], name: "index_games_on_team_one_type_and_team_one_id"
    t.index ["team_two_type", "team_two_id"], name: "index_games_on_team_two_type_and_team_two_id"
    t.index ["tournament_id"], name: "index_games_on_tournament_id"
  end

  create_table "high_school_teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "school_name"
    t.string "team_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "tournaments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "games", "fields"
  add_foreign_key "games", "tournaments"
end
```

**tournaments_controller.rb**

```
class TournamentsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    @tournament = Tournament.new(tournament_params)

    if @tournament.save
      redirect_to @tournament
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def tournament_params
      params
        .require(:tournament)
        .permit(:name, games_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :team_one_id, :team_two_id, :field_id, :date, :start_time])
    end
end
```

**request parameters in tournaments_controller#create**

```
{
  "authenticity_token"=>"iB4JefT9jRdiOFKok38OtjzMwd6Dv3hlHP/QZRtlFgMuVZfbn9PFD7Lebc1DuvfL6/IatDpS5CiubTci5MsCFg==",
  "tournament"=>{
    "name"=>"foo",
    "games_attributes"=>{
      "1577935885397"=>{
        "team_one_id"=>"high-school-team-2",
        "team_two_id"=>"club-team-2",
        "date"=>"",
        "start_time"=>"",
        "_destroy"=>"false"
      }
    }
  },
  "commit"=>"Create Tournament"
}
```

**tournament_params in tournaments_controller#create**

```
<ActionController::Parameters {
  "name"=>"foo",
  "games_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {
    "1577937916236"=><ActionController::Parameters {
      "_destroy"=>"false",
      "team_one_id"=>"high-school-team-2",
      "team_two_id"=>"club-team-2",
      "date"=>"",
      "start_time"=>""
    } permitted: true>
  } permitted: true>
} permitted: true>
```

It seems to me that the `tournament_params` match what the [accepts_nested_attributes documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) is expecting under One-to-many, so I don't see why there is an error.

> Nested attributes for an associated collection can also be passed in
>   the form of a hash of hashes instead of an array of hashes:

```
Member.create(
  name: 'joe',
  posts_attributes: {
    first:  { title: 'Foo' },
    second: { title: 'Bar' }
  }
)
```

> has the same effect as

```
Member.create(
  name: 'joe',
  posts_attributes: [
    { title: 'Foo' },
    { title: 'Bar' }
  ]
)
```

Edit:

**tournaments/new.html.erb**

```
<h1>Create a tournament</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', tournaments_path %>
```

**tournaments/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with model: @tournament, class: 'tournament-form' do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <section class="games">
    <%= f.fields_for :games do |game| %>
      <%= render 'game_fields', f: game %>
    <% end %>
    <hr>
    <p>
      <%= link_to_add_association "Add game", f, :games,
        data: {
          association_insertion_node: '.games',
          association_insertion_method: :prepend
        }
      %>
    </p>
  </section>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**tournaments/_game_fields.html.erb**

```
<section class="nested-fields">
  <hr>
  <p><strong>Game</strong></p>
  <%= render "games/form_fields", f: f %>
  <p><%= link_to_remove_association "Remove game", f %></p>
</section>
```

**games/_form_fields.html.erb**

```
<section>
  <% if HighSchoolTeam.all.count + ClubTeam.all.count < 2 %>
    <p>You neeed at least two teams to create a game. Create more high school and/or club teams first.</p>
  <% else %>
    <section class="game-form">
      <p>
        <%= f.label :team_one %><br>
        <%= f.select :team_one_id, nil, {}, class: "team-one-dropdown" do %>
          <optgroup label="High School Teams">
            <% HighSchoolTeam.all.each do |high_school_team| %>
              <option value="high-school-team-<%= high_school_team.id %>"><%= high_school_team.school_name %></option>
            <% end %>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="Club Teams">
            <% ClubTeam.all.each do |club_team| %>
              <option value="club-team-<%= club_team.id %>"><%= club_team.name %></option>
            <% end %>
          </optgroup>
        <% end %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= f.label :team_two %><br>
        <%= f.select :team_two_id, nil, {}, class: "team-two-dropdown" do %>
          <optgroup label="High School Teams">
            <% HighSchoolTeam.all.each do |high_school_team| %>
              <option value="high-school-team-<%= high_school_team.id %>"><%= high_school_team.school_name %></option>
            <% end %>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="Club Teams">
            <% ClubTeam.all.each do |club_team| %>
              <option value="club-team-<%= club_team.id %>"><%= club_team.name %></option>
            <% end %>
          </optgroup>
        <% end %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= f.label :field %><br>
        <%= f.collection_select(:field_id, Field.all, :id, :name) %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= f.label :date %><br>
        <%= f.date_field :date %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= f.label :start_time %><br>
        <%= f.time_field :start_time %>
      </p>
    </section>
  <% end %>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have problem saving team and not an issue of `Cocoon` gem.

Since you customize your select value to `club-team-id` and `high-school-team-id`. I think you just need to change it to something like this:

`<option value="HighSchoolTeam-<%= high_school_team.id %>"><%= high_school_team.school_name %></option>`

and

`<option value="ClubTeam-<%= club_team.id %>"><%= club_team.name %></option>`

Then the params will be

```
{
  "authenticity_token"=>"iB4JefT9jRdiOFKok38OtjzMwd6Dv3hlHP/QZRtlFgMuVZfbn9PFD7Lebc1DuvfL6/IatDpS5CiubTci5MsCFg==",
  "tournament"=>{
    "name"=>"foo",
    "games_attributes"=>{
      "1577935885397"=>{
        "team_one_id"=>"HighSchoolTeam-2",
        "team_two_id"=>"ClubTeam-2",
        "date"=>"",
        "start_time"=>"",
        "_destroy"=>"false"
      }
    }
  },
  "commit"=>"Create Tournament"
}
```

then you need to modified your params by:

```
# Adding before_action on top of your controller
before_action :modify_params, only: [:create, :update]

private
# Not the cleanest way, but this is what I can think of right now.
def modify_params
  params.dig(:tournament, :games_attributes).each do |game_id, game_attribute|
    team_one_type = game_attribute[:team_one_id].split('-').first
    team_one_id = game_attribute[:team_one_id].split('-').last

    team_two_type = game_attribute[:team_two_id].split('-').first
    team_two_id = game_attribute[:team_two_id].split('-').last

    params[:tournament][:games_attributes][game_id] = game_attribute.merge(
      team_one_type: team_one_type,
      team_one_id: team_one_id,
      team_two_type: team_two_type,
      team_two_id: team_two_id
    )
  end
end

# And update this method to allow team_one_type and team_two_type
def tournament_params
  params.require(:tournament)
    .permit(:name, games_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :team_one_id, :team_two_id, :team_one_type, :team_two_type, :field_id, :date, :start_time])
end
```

Comment: `inverse_of` does seem promising, but changing `has_many :games` to `has_many :games, inverse_of: :tournament` did not fix the issue for me. I'm getting the same errors, and I restarted my server.

Comment: `team_one_id` and `team_two_id` are existing records or new?

Comment: Ok, it seems like your issue is not `cocoon` gem, but you have issue saving `team_one` and `team_two`. You basically need to make sure, you send over `team_one_type` and `team_two_type` with their ids respectively, so that Rails know which class it should reference the team to.

Comment: `(2, Syosset, Braves, 2019-12-31 01:07:41.367913, 2019-12-31 01:07:41.367913)` and `(2, Foobars, 2019-12-31 01:07:52.697821, 2019-12-31 01:07:52.697821)` are existing records. `team_one_id`, `team_one_type`, `team_two_id`, and `team_two_type` are all columns for the `Games` table.

Comment: Hm, sending over `team_one_type` and `team_two_type` also seems promising. I'm not sure how I would/should do that though. I updated the question to include my views. Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205200/discussion-between-coco-and-adam-zerner).